# returning focus to textarea widget with button.on_click()

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I made a notebook for saving latex into PNGs that I can later import into PDFs.
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whwix.png)

I have buttons that add text to the textarea via .on_click(). Is it possible to set the focus back to the text area in the callback function?

Comment: Looking at ipywidget's code it looks like you can use the function `focus` to force to focus back on your textarea. Try to get the textarea reference on your callback function and use .focus on it, like: lambda change: my_textarea.focus()
The code:

https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/9326d28c474cb6d2b58876d469489a73e98f903a/python/ipywidgets/ipywidgets/widgets/domwidget.py

Comment: Above comment should be it...as long as you're working with the newest release (8.0) of ipywidgets (released Jan 28, 2022). The `focus` function was just added as per the [changelog](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/ec946cf9896bd485faaab78af91d5e4230d46f78/docs/source/changelog.md)

Comment: Focus or blur a widget. (#2664, #2692, #2691, #2690)

I interpret that as "Unblur or blur a widget."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.